# how to select row in mysql with max id

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to select row in mysql whose visitor id=1 and max id then it should be the last row as I focus in this picture[image]

but it is showing something else, it showing this output [image]

here the mysql code I tried 
SELECT *,max(id) FROM activity WHERE visitorid=1

Comment: Use ORDER BY to set the order and LIMIT 1 to pick the first one. `SELECT * FROM activity WHERE visitorid=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with:

```
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE visitorid = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

this will order your rows (where `visitorid = 1`) descending by `id` and select only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

When there exists multiple entries for an id in a table
 and you still want to fetch the latest, then
 filter the records in descending order of auto incremented primary key and limit to top record.

**Example**:

```
select * from activity 
 where visitorid = 1
 order by id desc
 limit 1
```